# How to measure SINAD of an audio signal?

Tags: matlab, signal-analysis, audio, snr, distortion

I tried to measure the SINAD and SNR of a recorded audio signal using MATLAB. The following is the process I did to measure the 2 parameters:
Firstly, I generated an FM modulated signal(1 kHz audio tone) at a particular frequency using a signal generator and connected it to an RTL-SDR. The RTL-SDR is connected to a PC with a loaded SDR# software (even GNURadio can do the operation). After tuning the RTL-SDR to generated RF signal, I was able to receive the 1 kHz audio tone. I recorded the sample stream for a small duration (1 minute) and loaded the recorded data in MATLAB. I used the in-built SINAD and SNR function to calculate the sensitivity and signal to noise ratio. Surprisingly, I receive the same values for both SINAD and SNR. But, When I look at the graphs for SINAD as well as SNR, it appears to be that both parameters are calculated wrongly.
[image]
[image]
From the graphs, It appears that both SNR and SINAD should have higher values like more than 60 dB.
If you have any ideas, on how to calculate these parameters in MATLAB, please let me know.

Comment: not quite sure whether the numbers are actually right, or you just misused the matlab functions. We'll need to see your code! Also, why don't you just go and write your own SINAD estimator? The formula is easy enough!

Comment: Since I am using a recorded audio stream for processing, how do I know the values of my noise and distortion content? The MATLAB code that I used was elementary, just loaded the .wav file, reshaped the audio sampled data into a column vector, and applied the inbuilt SINAD and SNR function. I presume that is completely wrong.  How do I calculate the noise and distortion from the recorded audio stream?

Comment: That's a surprising question from you, considering you've been considering  SINAD measurements a lot! You know that the signal in there is a single harmonic oscillation. So find the frequency of that and its power (in the easiest case: do a long FFT, find the max. absolute squared value). That's your signal energy. Sum up the total energy in the receiving (sum of absolute squared values). Subtract signal energy, get noise-and-distortion energy. Done!

Comment: Yeah. This looks doable. Thanks.

Comment: Hello Marcus,  I have done the necessary steps for finding the SINAD. Yet, I am not able to get convincing results. I do the following steps after reading the audio stream: long_fft = fft(audio sampled data);
signal_energy = max(abs(long_fft.^2));
total_energy = sum(abs(long_fft.^2));
noise_power = total_energy-signal_energy;    But even then, I am getting negative SINAD (even though I get a strong tone ). Am I missing anything fundamental? Thanks. Your suggestions have helped me.